# Python for check debug symbols

Tags: python, gdb, objdump

I am trying to made multiple platform script for checking if binary has a debug symbols. I want a whole script be written in python. I am wondering to evoke commands like `gdb` or `objdump`. for this purpose. What are your suggestions for the efficient use of this tools?

For example `objdump -g`  should return if there is any debug symbols, however it doesn't. Maybe someone know any API for python for checking debug symbols.

Comment: Any reason for C++ tag?

Comment: Can you use external libraries? https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/blob/master/examples/elf_show_debug_sections.py might help.

Comment: objdump `-g` is for STABS debug info, try `objdump -W`.

Comment: I am trying to do it on MacOs and as well `-g` and  `-W` is not recognized as a `objdump` option

Comment: I also noticed that after installation by qtframework installer there is no symbols in execs at all.